# Could Sasuke use the six paths of Pain?

Tags: naruto, boruto

I got into a hot conversation with a friend concerning how the Rinnengan works and ***I'd like to the clarify the requirements for using the 6 paths of pain***; 
[image]

> Just like how Nagato and Obito Uchiha could divide the six paths power accross a bunch of dead bodies, could Sasuke also use that technique in the same fashion, if the need arises?

Also, has it ever been mentioned if its possible to use the six paths technique on living people? (like divide the six paths across different individuals who are already alive?)

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_of_Pain), The Six Paths of Pain is

> an Outer Path technique that allows a *Rinnegan user* to manipulate up to six bodies as though they are their own. Since [Sasuke is one](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sasuke_Uchiha), he has access to it, although he's only using the Preta Path, as stated in the wiki.  [Also since it is based on the six Buddhist Paths of **Reincarnation**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_of_Pain), I don't think this applies to living people.

Comment: The numbering corresponds to the of the ordering of six buddhist paths but in general the concepts are entirely different thou @W.Are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%83s%C4%81ra_(Buddhism)

Comment: Can you specify how different it is? I mean, the Six Paths of Pain manipulates dead bodies. This manipulation, in itself, is influenced by the rebirth/reincarnation of someone into one of the six realms depending on their karma in the past life. And the link you put also talks about the same thing. And even if there were minor differences, it is expected as Naruto just draws influences from Buddhism and is not entirely about Buddhism itself.